# Variable parameter vs hardcoding

Tags: optimization, google-sheets, formulas

I have a large complex spreadsheet with ~200 tabs. It opens/loads very slowly (upto 5 minutes) due to multitudes of formula calculations. I am trying to optimize the formulas so the spreadsheet will open/load faster.

One of the most frequent calculations is to multiply about 60 cells in each tab by a variable in 'Sheet1!B4' (Sheet 1, cell B4). I expect this value to change maybe once in a year or so, which would require updating all 200 tabs in at least 60 cells each.

Will it be better to hard-code the value, and take the hit for updating it once a year in all the affected cells in all the tabs?

Or is it ok to reference it in some way, which does not impact the performance, and preferably makes it faster?

Here are the three options I am considering:

1. Hardcoded value: `=countif(C$10:C$30,$B60) * 10`
2. Reference cell: `=countif(C$10:C$30,$B60) * Sheet1!:B4`
3. Use Named Range of a single cell: `=countif(C$10:C$30,$B60) * PARAMETER_VAL`
   where `PARAMETER_VAL` is a named range referencing `Sheet1!B4`

Which of the above would be the fastest?

Is there any other way to make it faster, that I may be missing?

Comment: This might be better suited to webapps.stackexchange.com . Have you tried using array formulas to expand into neighboring cells? The fastest manner will always be to remove the formula entirely, leaving only a static value (i.e. moving the calculation to an apps script function that reads input from various cells on various tabs, computes the result arrays, and then writes the given array on the given tab).

Comment: If you know there are cells that are rarely updated, you may be better off computing those with a custom Apps Script function and execute them only when you need to or on a schedule.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
tehhowch and Argyll , these cells are dependent on other cells which are updated 1-2 times a day. People would like to see real-time updates. I could probably use onEdit trigger, but it might be triggering multiple times, and the script might time-out or overlap with someone else's edits... I don't think it is feasible, unless  there are finer points I am missing.

@pnuts Thanks for catching that, I have updated the post now :-)

Comment: for such big speadsheets I think it's much more suitable to use a proper database

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I agree. We are in the process of moving to a MySQL database, but until then...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that any of the three alternatives will have significative difference on the spreadsheet performance because the reference / named ranges point to a cell with a fixed value.

Related Q&A

- [Measurement of execution time of built-in functions for Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46923770/1595451)

Comment: Thanks for the link... I followed it and found some interesting threads. However, performance cannot be measured simply by t2-t1 in a production environment, especially with Cloud. It is difficult to predict the load on the servers and the network at any given moment of time, as well as unknown design variables like Google's cache-refresh rates etc. My best option would be to actually understand how the internal caching is implemented for various function calls, or do the testing in an isolated network environment.

Answer (score 0):

I thought maybe once a year let the spreadsheet do the math after updating your variable that all the cells use and then 'copy/paste (only values)' and save as 'someotherfile'. That way all the updated values will be hardcoded which probably will speed things up hugely.

But are you prepared to go through all 200 tabs once a year to do that? I don't know how much time you are loosing through the year having to wait 5 minutes each time you access the file...

Maybe even you can do 'copy/paste as values' while having selected more than one tab (like all of them at the same time), but I use libre which might be behaving different than excel does and I don't even know if this is possible in any of them and your system might run out of memory too (I never tried such a thing).