# What tools are the equivalent of a profiler and a debugger for working with a web application such as google sheets

Tags: debugging, optimization, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a google sheet with multiple tabs.  At times it is very slow.
I've found several generic articles on speeding up sheets, and have improved the lag from minutes to seconds.

I've asked this question before on WebApplications, but just get lists of things to check.

How do you debug, trace and profile a spreadsheet, specifically a Google sheet?

Please note:  I'm NOT asking how to debug/profile/trace google API scripts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measurement of execution time of built-in functions for Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923770/measurement-of-execution-time-of-built-in-functions-for-spreadsheet)

Answer (score -1):

You might use

- Google Apps Script (for details  see [Measurement of execution time of built-in functions for Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46923770/1595451=)
- Google Chrome Developer Tools (related [Google Sheets Debugging Endless Calculations and Slow Load Time (Chrome Dev Tools)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64339223/1595451))

Answer (score -2):

it's simple, avoid multiple formulae such as "formula per row". instead use ArrayFormulas. 4 columns of 1000 rows in each one formula = 4000 formulae - eg. you need just 4 ArrayFormulas. less formulae = less calculations = less slowdown.

and also avoid (if possible) heavy formulae like `QUERY`, `VLOOKUP`, multiple `IMPORTRANGE`... if possible use `DGET` and of course less conditional formatting

also check for empty rows and delete them. ArrayFormulas are faster with fewer rows

Comment: Not what I asked.