# Google Sheets Debugging Endless Calculations and Slow Load Time (Chrome Dev Tools)

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Working with a Google Sheet that has grown in complexity and size over time and is now calculating endlessly and really slow to open. The sheet has a large amount of data, formulas and import ranges.

I have read best practices on how to speed up sheets [link](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slow-google-sheets/). Does anyone know how to do advanced trouble shooting in Chrome Dev tools to see what formulas are running when and help narrow down what could be causing the problem?

I have used Chrome Dev Tools and the Performance Monitor, but can't see how to locate actual formula [Ex: Sum() or VLOOKUP()] names/location from within the sheet since they are nested under so many layers of functions. (Ex: Function Call > b > P.I2b > p.$Ma > etc)

[image: Chrome Dev Tool Performance Screen Shot]

Comment: @Calculuswhiz While there are some functions that depends on the server (i.e. GOOGLEFINANCE) most of the spreadsheet calculation is done on the client side.

Comment: How much data is in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Current data size is about 500 rows and 30 columns. I'm trying to find a more general solution to pinpoint the issues there the calculations are getting hung up.

Comment: 500 rows and 30 columns isn't that big, I typically don't get slowed down until I am around 4000 rows.  Try to avoid using the same importrange() in multiple formulas, import it once into another sheet, then reference that cell.  Then it only has to call importrange once.