# How to check formula speed or compare speed between formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to check which method is faster in Google Sheets?

For example:
I have a big table to import. 20 columns and 5000 rows.
As this is only a part of big spreadsheet my concern is if this may slow down my work.

I need only 6 columns from this table and they are scattered (let's say Col1 , Col3, Col5,Col6, Col20)
I hesitate between:

- 5 IMPORTRANGE formulas that will import one or 2 column each.

  1 IMPORTRANGE formula that takes whole table nested with query that
  extracts columns I need.

I think about general tool that woould help with this kind of problems.

Comment: I don't think there is a tool like that or a way to do that because it depends on the source and target file. I would say try both methods and see what gives you the results faster when you update the formulas. But if 1 importrange can handle the full data then go for it. It would be faster than 5 smaller importranges. You only split the importranges when the data is too much to be handled by 1 importrange.

Comment: I rather think about a script that would check system time, run the formula, and then check again when calculation is finished. And maybe to get better accuracy - run formula 100 times and get average time. It's very difficult to check manually when calculation time is lower than 1 sec. I have more than 20 filters and queries run in my dashboard once I change one parameter so optimization of every step is very important for me.  I googled the problem with no result.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, are these thread and report useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46923770 and https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/b00be25a02ec283689480ac8138cbfeb If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.