# Running Count is Slow in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Here's my way of calculating running count by groups in Sheets:

`=LAMBDA(a,INDEX(if(a="",,COUNTIFS(a,a,row(a),"<="&row(a)))))(B4:B)`

The complexity of this formula is R^2 = 1000000 operations for 1K rows. I'd love to make more efficient formula, and tried combinations of `LABMDA` and `SCAN`. For now I've found only the way to do it fast with 1 group at a time:

`=INDEX(IF(B4:B=" Corn",SCAN(0,B4:B,LAMBDA(i,v,if(v=" Corn",i+1,i))),))`

Can we do the same for all groups? Do you have an idea?

---

Note: the script solution would use object and `hash` to make it fast.

[image]

---

### Legal Tests

We have a list of `N` items total with `m` groups. Group `m(i)` is a unique item which may repeat randomly. Samlpe dataset:

```
a
b
b
b
a
```

↑ Sample for 5 items total and 2 groups: `N=5`; `m=2`. Groups are "a" and "b"

The task is to find the function which will work faster for different numbers of `N` and `m`:

1. Case #1. 1000+ accurances of an item from a group `m(i)`
2. Case #2. 1000+ different groups `m`
3. General case sagnificant number of total items `N` ~ 50K+

### Playground

Samlpe Google Sheet with 50K rows of data. Please click on the button 'Use Tamplate':

[Test Sheet with 50K values](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vQu7hVr7FwH8H5N8JOlOGfvjlJgKtpfoM2DPPjgUaLo/template/preview)

### Speed Results

Tested solutions:

1. [`Countifs`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1euWuW5FJIqRz7Nt2jcpesZmcliDeeiMxRWyeIH7-ifQ/edit#gid=0) from the question and [`Countif`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TgC29Yh2vaOyxhrRRr394aX_RObWFmqPLf3xRjcgAYc/edit#gid=0) and from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74389906/5372400).
2. [`Xlookup`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LSisdg010ENP3F5eSz8Buvb69-uzJHtlV2gTZ1F-G34/edit#gid=0) from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74405498/5372400)
3. [Complex `Match`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZyuSYqJJe7VQRjZUgqdBcBbNkP7njfCqlTRohzHIoFc/edit#gid=0) logic from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413414/5372400)
4. [`Sorting` logic](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12lAEt86lL6lalYbIDuRif16paOCJHi3pJA6d-jNbVZQ/edit#gid=0) from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74441904/5372400)

In my enviroment, the `sorting` option works faster than other provided solutions. Test results are [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12lAEt86lL6lalYbIDuRif16paOCJHi3pJA6d-jNbVZQ/edit#gid=501018673), tested with the [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74443574/5372400).

Comment: _find the function which will work faster for different numbers of `N` and `m`_ — it may be that the three cases you present would each require a solution of their own. The performance of most answers below depends a lot on the number of groups in data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Sorting` algorithm

The idea is to use `SORT` in order to reduce the complexity of the calculation. Sorting is the built-in functionality and [it works faster](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/) than `countifs`.

1. Sort columns and their indexes
2. Find the place where each new element of a group starts
3. Create a counter of elements for sorted range
4. Sort the result back using indexes from step 1

[image]

Data is in range `A2:A`

### 1. Sort + Indexes

`=SORT({A2:A,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A))})`

### 2. Group Starts

`C2:C` is a range with sorted groups

`=MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A)),LAMBDA(v,if(v=1,0,if(INDEX(C2:C,v)<>INDEX(C2:C,v-1),1,0))))`

### 3. Counters

Count the item of each group by the column of `0/1` values, 1 - where group starts:

`=SCAN(0,F2:F,LAMBDA(ini,v,IF(v=1,1,ini+1)))`

### 4. Sort the resulting countes back

`=SORT(H2:H,D2:D,1)`

## The Final Solution

Suggested by [Tom Sharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894917/tom-sharpe):

> cut out one stage of the calculation by omitting the map and going
> straight to a scan like this:

`=LAMBDA(a,INDEX(if(a="",, LAMBDA(srt, SORT( SCAN(1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)), LAMBDA(ini,v,if(v=1,1,if(INDEX(srt,v,1)<>INDEX(srt,v-1,1),1,ini+1)))), index(srt,,2),1) ) (SORT({a,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a))})))))(A2:A)`

↑ In my tests this solution is faster.

I pack it into the named function. Sample file with the solution:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OSnLuCh-duW4eWH3Y6eqrJM8nU1akmjXJsluFFEkw6M/edit#gid=0

this image explains the logic and the speed of sorting:

[image]

↑ read more [about the speed test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74443574/5372400)

Comment: Hi @Max that seems pretty optimal to me - everything linear except the sort which will be log-lin and is very fast. Only suggestion is you could cut out one stage of the calculation by omitting the map and going straight to a scan like this =LAMBDA(a,INDEX(if(a="",, LAMBDA(srt, SORT( SCAN(1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)), LAMBDA(ini,v,if(v=1,1,if(INDEX(srt,v,1)<>INDEX(srt,v-1,1),1,ini+1)))), index(srt,,2),1) ) (SORT({a,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a))})))))(A2:A)

Comment: Hi @tom-sharpe! Thanks, in my tests your way even a bit faster. Will change the answer!

Comment: Here is an application of your method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711785/google-sheets-latest-date-of-each-summary-value-conditional-formatting/74723296#74723296

Answer (score 3):

## `Transpose` groups `m` = 5

I've found a possible way for a small amount of counted groups.

In my tests: 20K rows and 5 groups => cumulative count worked faster with this function:

```
INDEX(if(B4:B="",,LAMBDA(eq,BYROW(index(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(BYCOL(eq,LAMBDA(c,query("-"&SCAN(0,c,LAMBDA(i,v,i+v)),,2^99))))," -"))*eq),LAMBDA(r,sum(r))))(--(B4:B=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B4:B))))))
```

It's ugly, but for now I cannot do a better version as `bycol` function does not produce arrays.

## Apps Script

The perfect solution would be to have "hash"-like function in [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets):

```
/** runningCount
 * 
 * @param {Range} data
 * 
 * @CustomFunction
 * 
 */
function runningCount(data) {
  var obj = {};
  var l = data[0].length;
  var k;
  var res = [], row;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    row = []
    for (var ii = 0; ii < l; ii++) {
      k = '' + data[i][ii];
      if (k === '') {
        row.push('');
      } else {
        if (!(k in obj)) {
          obj[k] = 1;
        } else {
          obj[k]++;
        }
        row.push(obj[k]);
      }
    }
    res.push(row);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
=QUERY(
  REDUCE(
    {"", 0},
    B4:B10000,
    LAMBDA(
      acc,
      cur,
      {
        acc;
        cur, XLOOKUP(
               cur,
               INDEX(acc, 0, 1),
               INDEX(acc, 0, 2),
               0,
               0,
               -1
             ) + 1
      }
    )
  ),
  "SELECT Col2 OFFSET 1",
  0
)
```

A bit better than R^2. Works fast enough on 10 000 rows. On 100 000 rows it works, but it is quite slow.

[image]

Comment: Hi @kishkin! Thank you very much for posting this and other answer. I think these solutions are genius. I comment this because I've started a bounty on this question and wanted to let you know about it. My tests are gathered in my answer. I've also made a new testing database here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vQu7hVr7FwH8H5N8JOlOGfvjlJgKtpfoM2DPPjgUaLo/template/preview

Comment: Hi @kishkin! I've awarded this answer because it should be the most efficient way as it "repeats" HASH-way of working with data: find the first entry from the end by key. Pity, real tests shown this did not happen: my test files timed out with this formula. I suppose, `XLOOKUP` and other ways cannot be oprimized this way using Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach. Works roughly 4 times faster than the first one.

```
=LAMBDA(
    shift,
    ref,
    big_ref,
    LAMBDA(
        base_ref,
        big_ref,
        ARRAYFORMULA(
            IF(
                A2:A = "",,
                    MATCH(VLOOKUP(A2:A, base_ref, 2,) + ROW(A2:A), big_ref,) - VLOOKUP(A2:A, base_ref, 3,)
            )
        )
    )
    (
        ARRAYFORMULA(
            {
                ref,
                SEQUENCE(ROWS(ref)) * shift,
                MATCH(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ref)) * shift, big_ref,)
            }
        ),
        big_ref
    )
)
(
    10 ^ INT(LOG10(ROWS(A:A)) + 1),
    UNIQUE(A2:A),
    SORT(
        {
            MATCH(A2:A, UNIQUE(A2:A),) * 10 ^ INT(LOG10(ROWS(A:A)) + 1) + ROW(A2:A);
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(A2:A))) * 10 ^ INT(LOG10(ROWS(A:A)) + 1)
        }
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of kishkin's second approach that offloads much of the lookup table setup to lambdas early on. The changes in logic are not that big, but they seem to benefit the formula quite a bit:

| 5 uniques | 5000 rows | 4000 rows | 3000 rows | 2000 rows | 1000 rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lambda offload | 14.87x | 14.45x | 10.04x | 10.50x | 7.05x |
| sort redux | 7.73x | 5.89x | 4.89x | 3.96x | 2.24x |
| max makhrov sort | 4.23x | 4.52x | 3.65x | 3.31x | 1.95x |
| array countifs | 2.59x | 2.66x | 2.55x | 2.56x | 2.90x |
| kishkin2 | 0.83x | 0.80x | 0.81x | 1.03x | 1.19x |
| naïve countif | 1.00x | 1.00x | 1.00x | 1.00x | 1.00x |

I primarily tested using [this benchmark](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a95u60kFycEk2mrqWZqwvzLyEED0_uc_bpAmkgsmzhw/edit#gid=794501593) and would welcome testing by others.

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    groups, 
    lambda( 
      uniques, shiftingFactor, 
      lambda( 
        shiftedOrdinals, 
        lambda( 
          ordinalLookup, 
          lambda( 
            groupLookup, 
            iferror( 
              match( 
                vlookup(groups, groupLookup, 2, true) + row(groups), 
                ordinalLookup, 
                1 
              ) 
              - 
              vlookup(groups, groupLookup, 3, true) 
            ) 
          )( 
            sort( 
              { 
                uniques, 
                shiftedOrdinals, 
                match(shiftedOrdinals, ordinalLookup, 1) 
              } 
            ) 
          ) 
        )( 
          sort( 
            { 
              match(groups, uniques, 1) * shiftingFactor + row(groups); 
              shiftedOrdinals 
            } 
          ) 
        ) 
      )(sequence(rows(uniques)) * shiftingFactor) 
    )( 
      unique(groups), 
      10 ^ int(log10(rows(groups)) + 1)
    ) 
  )(A2:A) 
)
```

The formula performs best when the number of groups is small. Here are some benchmark results with a simple numeric [50k row corpus](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O-frUnrc0LZK30TFKzF6hM-V_eNhBVewfTnAfDdTYTQ/edit#gid=1181054011) where the number of uniques differs:

| 50k rows | 11 uniques | 1000 uniques |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lambda offload | 14.41x | 3.57x |
| array countifs | 1.00x | 1.00x |

Performance degrades as the number of groups increases, and I even got a few incorrect results when the number of groups approached 20k.

Comment: Hy @doubleunary. Thank you for the affort, in my tests the formula works fast. But the results are wrong. Tests are here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UGm5NcFkqpm340idCwKW2ZhEwtRr7mhv8Qg9QrGSK0g/edit#gid=0. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Your test seems good. It looks like the formula will get incorrect results when the first appearances of unique groups do not take place in Sheets lexicographical order. I may take another look at this later when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, it will probably be more efficient, but you'll have to try:

`=Byrow(B4:B,lambda(each,if(each="","",countif(B4:each,each))))`

or

`=map(B4:B,lambda(each,if(each="","",countif(B4:each,each))))`

Let me know!

Comment: Thanks, Martín! This works fine. And the formula is small. It is still slow due to the way it counts: each cell by each cell.

Comment: Yes, Martín. Some business tasks as caclulating discount depending on the number of service purchased reqire this