# How to assign version depending on cell value in column using scripts?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

The google spreadsheet has two columns. The first column contains some repeated values such as "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A". In the second column I want to write version count in the second column. The screenshot is attached for reference. How could I achieve this with scripts?[image]

Comment: Related question: [Running Count is Slow in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74389341/1330560)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION

You can try this script:

```
function countDuplicates(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var vals = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(x => x != "").flat(Infinity);
  for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
    var count = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < i + 1; j++){
      if(vals[i] == vals[j])
        count++;
    }
    sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue([count]); // sets the count right beside the value 
  }
}
```

It gets the column of values, and is then run through a for loop to check each iteration of that value, after which the total count is set on the cell beside it.

### OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a version with script:

```
function countVersions(){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues()
  const rangeVersions = sheet.getRange("B2:B")

  var versions = []
  var processedValues = []

  for(i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    if(values[i][0] != "") {
      processedValues.push(values[i][0])
      var filteredArray = processedValues.filter(n => n === values[i][0])
      var count = filteredArray.length
      versions.push([count])
    }
    else {versions.push([''])}
  }

  rangeVersions.setValues(versions)
}
```

And a version with formula:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",COUNTIF(A2:each,each))))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the formula AND for using `byRow/Lambda`. FWIW, an "old school" solution is described in infospired's [Running Count of Multiple Values in a List in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/running-count-of-multiple-values/) (which probably means that there is an equivalent question in StackOverflow)

Comment: @Tedinoz Also "old school" would be significantly faster.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you, I did not know that. This provoked me to provide the old-school answer pus a few more. :)

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase @Tanaike, "please consider this as just one way of answering the question".

#1 **The "old-school" method**: for the sake of completeness and courtesy [infospired](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/running-count-of-multiple-values/)

Enter this in Cell B2:

`=Array_Constrain(iferror(sort({row(A2:A)-row(A2)+2-match(sort(A2:A),sort(A2:A),0),SORT(ROW(A2:A)+2-row(A2)+2,A2:A,1)},2,1),),9^9,1)`

---

#2 **Max Makhrov**: "my way of calculating running count by groups in Sheets" [Running Count is Slow in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74389341/1330560)

Enter this in Cell C2:

`=LAMBDA(a,INDEX(if(a="",,COUNTIFS(a,a,row(a),"<="&row(a)))))(A2:A)`

---

#3 **kishkin-Mark#1**: "Another approach. Works roughly 4 times faster than the first one." [Running Count is Slow in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413414/1330560)

Enter this is cell D2:

```
=LAMBDA(
    shift,
    ref,
    big_ref,
    LAMBDA(
        base_ref,
        big_ref,
        ARRAYFORMULA(
            IF(
                A2:A = "",,
                    MATCH(VLOOKUP(A2:A, base_ref, 2,) + ROW(A2:A), big_ref,) - VLOOKUP(A2:A, base_ref, 3,)
            )
        )
    )
    (
        ARRAYFORMULA(
            {
                ref,
                SEQUENCE(ROWS(ref)) * shift,
                MATCH(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ref)) * shift, big_ref,)
            }
        ),
        big_ref
    )
)
(
    10 ^ INT(LOG10(ROWS(A:A)) + 1),
    UNIQUE(A2:A),
    SORT(
        {
            MATCH(A2:A, UNIQUE(A2:A),) * 10 ^ INT(LOG10(ROWS(A:A)) + 1) + ROW(A2:A);
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(A2:A))) * 10 ^ INT(LOG10(ROWS(A:A)) + 1)
        }
    )
)
```

---

#4 **kishkin-Mark#1**: winner of the 500 point bounty on [Running Count is Slow in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74405498/1330560)

Enter this is Cell F2: **Note**, this formula defines the last line of the data range

```
=QUERY(
  REDUCE(
    {"", 0},
    B2:B15,
    LAMBDA(
      acc,
      cur,
      {
        acc;
        cur, XLOOKUP(
               cur,
               INDEX(acc, 0, 1),
               INDEX(acc, 0, 2),
               0,
               0,
               -1
             ) + 1
      }
    )
  ),
  "SELECT Col2 OFFSET 1",
  0
)
```

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]